# Is there a difference between ftp.mysite.com and using an IP directly?

Tags: url, dns, ftp

Lets say I use DNS to configure ftp.mysite.com to my site's IP, I want to give clients the credentials to use the ftp site. Can I give them the URL (ftp.mysite.com) OR should I give then the IP directly (even though the URL points to that IP).

Am I risking compatibility issues of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use an IP address, always use a domain name. A domain name is less likely to change and carries more information than an IP address.

While a domain name is indeed just an alias to an IP address, a single IP address can be used for multiple domains. This is common with virtual hostings.

In this case, an IP address may not carry enough information. This more common with HTTP, where a domain name, that is otherwise lost in domain-to-IP resolution, is provided to an HTTP server using `Host:` HTTP header.

FTP protocol has a similar mechanics, the `HOST` command. But as that command was introduced relatively recently, it is actually quite rare that an FTP server relies on this. Even on shared hostings, a domain is usually included in an FTP username to allow even FTP clients, that do not (yet) support the `HOST` command.

See also [Do the SSH or FTP protocols tell the server to which domain I am trying to connect?](https://serverfault.com/q/672270/168875#672403)

Answer (score 0):

there is no deference. you can give either you IP or your domain name. once people have the domain, they can get your IP very easy.
the domain can be better choice in case the IP is going to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Most FTP servers are hosted on port 21 (or 22 for SFTP).
ftp.mysite.com usually points to localhost:21 or localhost:22

So there is no difference, except for the ports.

Comment: is there though? I mean...I could tell my clients to use ftp.mysite.com and use port 30 no?

Comment: Correct, however your ftp is on any port, and ftp.mysite.com should redirect to that arbitrary port